# Reuse of rpc cookie authentication

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc, authentication

I'm looking for clarification of an answer on original [thread](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46782/rpc-cookie-authentication) where the accepted answer [states](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/48524/50560) "This option (the authentication result from Python) can be specified multiple times"

As I understand this means the rpcath= xxxx:xyxyxxyxxxyxyxxyxxyxyxxyxxyxyx can be used on several instances of Bitcoincore on different machines.

Is this correct?

Comment: You're talking about rpcauth authentication, or cookie authentication? They're separate mechanisms.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clear. rpc. Not cookie.