# Accessing RPC with RPC Auth or .cookie

Tags: json-rpc

Starting to interface with my btc node and I'm getting an RPC error 401 unoathorized error when running the below code.  My RPC_Auth (rpcuser:rpcpassword) is correct.  Is there something else I need to configure?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
rpc_url = f"http://{rpc_auth}@{rpc_host}:{rpc_port}"
rpc_client = AuthServiceProxy(rpc_url, timeout=120)

try:

    peer_info = rpc_client.getpeerinfo()
    print(peer_info)
except JSONRPCException as e:
    print(f"RPC Error: {e}")
```

Comment: When you set `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` in your `bitcoin.conf`, did you also restart Bitcoin Core so that those changes apply?

Comment: I set rpcauth using the rpcauth.py file during my IBD so that hasnt changed.

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46782/rpc-cookie-authentication helped answer all my questions and get this figured out.